# Java 8 Acces Denied while running process with arguments

Tags: java-8, process, processbuilder

In my program i need to run exe file in process. I'm doing it with ProcessBuilder. When i'm putting to code only directory and exe name, process is running normally, but i want to put arguments. When i'm trying it i'm getting exception with Acces Denied message.
It's my code:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Directory", "file.exe", argument1).start();
```

What is wrong with it?

My earlier code, that worked but without arguments was:

```
 String folder = "C:\\Directory";
 String exe = "File.exe";  
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
 pb.command(folder + exe);
 pb.start();
```

With this code i was able to see started process in ProcessManager.

Comment: can you post the log? and [try to disable UAC](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/)

Comment: It's not working with disabled UAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to execute `C:\\Directory` which is not allowed.

The full path of the executable must be in the first argument to the constructor, so:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Directory\\file.exe", argument1).start();
```

This is assuming `C:\Directory\file.exe` is the program you are trying to run.

Update: In your original code you have:

```
 String folder = "C:\\Directory";
 String exe = "File.exe";
```

so 'folder + exe' is `C:\DirectoryFile.exe` so you the equivalent code is:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\DirectoryFile.exe", argument1).start();
```

Comment: With this code i can't find this process in ProcessManager. My earlier code  that worked was:        ProcessBuilder pr = new ProcessBuilder();
        pr.command(folder + exe);       when folder was Directory without exe.file and exe was only file .exe.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to execute?

Comment: Some .exe file, that allows to use arguments which i used.

Comment: Your original code is executing `C:\DirectoryFile.exe` so use `"C:\\DirectoryFile.exe"` as the first parameter

Comment: With this code i can't find my process in process manager: Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Directory\\file.exe", "argument1").start();

Comment: i don't know why, but this code not running this process. How can i add arguments to my original code?